# Searching for the most suitable "gridview"

Tags: android, gridview

I'm developing an Android App which, amongst other things, displays the result of a sql query, similar to what is shown on the following image: http://www.dataprix.com/files/uploads/Oracle_SQL_Developer.jpg.

I'd like to use a gridview, but unless a custom one is created, the standard gridview only suppoers vertical scrolling, but no horizontal scrolling. Although it is possible to put a gridview into a gallery control (with horizontal scrolling), I'm not quite sure if that's the best option here.

Would it be possible to display only part of the data, depending on the resolution of the display, and if you want to see more, you have to click on the "Next 20 entries"-button to "scroll" horizontally?

Or are there other, more suitable ways to display the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a TableLayout within a ScrollView and a HorizontalScrollView which so far suits my needs.